# Ubuntu 18 dual install loop

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 18.04, live-usb

Trying to install Ubuntu 18 alongside Windows 10. I have got UEFI boot using USB stick to Ubuntu boot options but it just reboot cycles to this point whatever Ubuntu options are chosen.

Machine Specs:
AMD A6-5400K
MSI Board FMZ-A75IA-E53(MS-7792)
Radeon HD graphics Ram 4Gb 64 Bit

Windows specs Windows 10 Pro (Secure Boot disabled)

Help as below means this is no longer an install issue therefore have progressed as [question regarding display issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089558/ubuntu-18-04-amd).

Comment: Many MSI AMD  boards need boot parameters. But have you updated UEFI to latest available version? Check if UEFI fast boot is off as well as Windows fast start up. I know Gigabyte boards need iommu setting changed and iommu=soft boot parameter, not sure about AMD boards.  And many seem to need acpi=off. So you may need to experiment.

Comment: Sorry that is really unhelpful to say I need to experiment. Please refer to the specific board settings

Comment: Did you try changing iommu settings in UEFI? Did you try booting with iommu=soft boot parameter, did you try with acpi=off boot parameter. You add them to grub menu, by replacing quiet splash on linux line. Use e to edit grub menu. Similar to adding the nomodeset boot parameter for graphic issues: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Comment: adding both iommu=soft and acpi=off gives MODSIGN: Couldnt get UEFI db list.

Comment: ok getting somewhere - nomodeset now boots 'without installing' tho resolution is fixed at 1024x768

Comment: Try with UEFI Secure Boot off, but UEFI on, (not BIOS/CSM/Legacy).

Comment: So I have installed the dual boot and this runs as expected. I have to have the nomodeset permanently in Grub with nano /etc/default/grub and update-grub but I cannot find a way to change screen resolution. I have installed AMD drivers but that seems to have made no difference

Comment: Generally is using proprietary drivers, you do not use nomodeset. Try booting without it. You can just edit it out from grub menu and boot for a one time test.

Comment: Stuck on boot loop without nomodeset

Comment: I feel this being originally raised as an install issue and having successfully installed thanks to your help oldfred I should create a new question focusing on 'display'. If you could kindly summarise your comments as an answer I will be happy to mark as a solution, referencing the new question

Comment: Not sure which of several suggestions really worked. Better to have answer with just the parts that work. You can post your own and in a few days accept it.

Comment: It was nomodeset that moved things on, getting the system to a stable state that does not involve install - therefore that would be an acceptable answer (it removes other potential issues such as BIOS, corrupt USB iso image,Windows refusing to f**k off etc) and at least allows me to apt-get setup other stuff while investigating. Many thanks